# Disable USB Controller in vmware vSphere Client 8.0.1.00000

Tags: usb, vmware, vsphere

I would like to disable usb controller of a vm so that one will not be able to add usb controller from the UI of the vSphere.

I have tried to change the vmx file and add `devices.hotplug = FALSE` but, as the field suggests, it only works when the vm is powered off. I would like to cause the same behavior so it would work even when the vm is powered on.

It would be great to have another vmx field that can cause this behavior or another way to disable usb controller that is not related to the vmx file.